# Can I get the mac address of an eddystone-UID beacon signal in ios

Tags: ios, ibeacon, mac-address, eddystone

I'm trying to retrieve the mac address from an Eddystone-uid packet on ios. Android allows me access to it easily. I know that on ios, the CoreBluetooth library obfuscates pretty much all received ibeacon data values. Eddystone is much more open on ios, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the mac address data, or if it's available at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanning for Eddystone beacons on iOS uses CoreBluetooth APIs to access the Bluetooth LE service advertisements.  You cannot access the raw MAC address of the beacon advertisement using these APIs (or any other public APIs) on iOS.  Apple blocks access to the Bluetooth MACs out of privacy and anti-tracking concerns,  CoreBluetooth will assign an auto-generated GUID to each unique Bluetooth device which correlates to the MAC, but does not have the same value.

Bottom line: while you can access the Bluetooth MAC on Android **you cannot do it on iOS.**  Sorry.

Comment: This doesn't surprise me as I've tried in to use CoreBluetooth to read iBeacon data in the past, with no luck. I figured that if iOS gives me full access to Eddystone uid info, it may also allow access to the sender's mac address in that format as well.

Comment: The Eddystone UID identifier is just a series of bytes parsed out of the service data in the received advertisement.  CoreBluetooth lets you read these bytes, but not the MAC.